# Get POST data and return with res.end() - encoding issue

Tags: python, node.js, encoding, utf-8

I'm sending POST data from Python program to Node.JS-server and return with res.end. Here's the python code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import requests
value = u"Этот текст в кодировке Unicode"
url = "http://localhost:3000/?source=test"
headers = {'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'}
r = requests.post(url, data=value.encode("utf-8"))
print r.text
```

And here's how I process data in Node.JS:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    req.setEncoding = "utf8"
    var queryData = '';
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        req.on('data', function(data) {
            queryData += data;
        });
        req.on('end', function() {
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            });
            res.end(queryData)
        });

    } else {
        // sending '405 - Method not allowed' if GET
        res.writeHead(405, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.end();
    }
}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
```

As result I get:

```
$ python test.py 
Ð­ÑÐ¾Ñ ÑÐµÐºÑÑ Ð² ÐºÐ¾Ð´Ð¸ÑÐ¾Ð²ÐºÐµ Unicode
```

How should I set encoding properly to get "Этот текст в кодировке Unicode" as a result? Thanks.

Comment: The encoding should be correct, I haven't dealt with python much but could it be an issue on the return side of not print unicode? I assume though that the second hash sets python to default to uft8 for printing as well.

Comment: Node part looks alright. What if you post with `curl` or `wget`? (For me it's working as expected, I bet it's python's problem.) On a side note, unicode is not encoding, utf8 is.

Comment: @elmigranto If I POST with CURL, everything works OK. However, I've tried to request with python interactive shell. >>> r.headers['Content-Encoding']
'utf-8' and if I get >>> r.encoding
'ISO-8859-1'

Comment: Check out docs on `requests` module and investigate what it needs to understand utf8 properly (which headers it expects, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the charset of the returning data:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
});
```

At the top you are setting the "decoding" of the coming data, but never set the out going response.

Comment: At first look in Python interactive shell your solution worked. Let me check on production, and if it's OK, I'll mark your answer as solved )

Answer (score 1):

setEncoding in Node.JS is a method so instead of = use the following:

`req.setEncoding('utf8');`

See example here:
http://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Comment: In the Node.JS part of your code, you have: `req.setEncoding = "utf8"` You can try changing it to req.setEncoding('utf8');